# Error in seemingly correct template code - what's wrong?

Tags: c++, parsing, templates, eigen

I am using the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) template library for matrices. I am puzzled by compiler error in the `Foo2` class while `Foo1` (not templated)  with almost the same code passes just fine:

```
#include<Eigen/Core>

struct Foo1{
    static Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1> bar(const Eigen::Matrix<double,6,1>& v6){
        return v6.head<3>();
    }
};

template<typename Scalar>
struct Foo2{
    static Eigen::Matrix<Scalar,3,1> bar(const Eigen::Matrix<Scalar,6,1>& v6){
         return v6.head<3>();
    }
};
```

gives (clang 3.4, gcc 4.8):

```
a.cc:8:53: error: expected expression
        static Vec3 bar(const Vec6& v6){ return v6.head<3>(); }
                                                           ^
1 error generated.
```

(does it mean the compiler parses the `<` as "less than " instead of start of template arguments?).

Any clue as to what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what it means. You need to tell the compiler that `head` is a template and not a data member:

```
return v6.template head<3>();
```

The reason that the compiler can't tell is because it doesn't know what the instantiated type of `v6` is (since it depends on the template parameter `Scalar`).

We had [a question with the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20868600/150634) earlier today. For a more in-depth explanation, see [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/150634).

Comment: A popular topic today :)

Comment: Is it always that I use template function of a type which depends on the current template context that the `template` keyword should be specified?

Comment: Ah OK, I see you added links I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @eudoxos Exactly. Otherwise it will assume it's a data member. If it didn't have this rule, the expression would be ambiguous.